# How to change the font size of a QInputDialog in PyQt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

**The case of a simple message box**

I have figured out how to change the font size in simple PyQt dialog windows. Take this example:

```
    # Create a custom font
    # ---------------------
    font = QFont()
    font.setFamily("Arial")
    font.setPointSize(10)

    # Show simple message box
    # ------------------------
    msg = QMessageBox()
    msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Question)
    msg.setText("Are you sure you want to delete this file?")
    msg.setWindowTitle("Sure?")
    msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok | QMessageBox.Cancel)
    msg.setFont(font)
    retval = msg.exec_()
    if retval == QMessageBox.Ok:
        print('OK')
    elif retval == QMessageBox.Cancel:
        print('CANCEL')
```

The key to changing the font size is that you actually have a 'handle' to your message box. The variable `msg` is available to tweak the message box to your needs before showing it with `msg.exec_()`.

**The case of a simple input dialog**

The problem about the input dialog is that such handle is not present. Take this example:

```
    # Show simple input dialog
    # -------------------------
    filename, ok = QInputDialog.getText(None, 'Input Dialog', 'Enter the file name:')
    if(ok):
        print('Name of file = ' + filename)
    else:
        print('Cancelled')
```

The input dialog object is created on-the-fly. I have no way to tweak it to my needs (eg. apply a different font).

Is there a way to get a handle to this `QInputDialog` object, before showing it?

**EDIT :**

I was adviced in the comments to try it with an HTML snippet:

```
    filename, ok = QInputDialog.getText(None, 'Input Dialog', '<html style="font-size:12pt;">Enter the file name:</html>')
```

The result is as follows:

[image]

As you can see, the text input field has still the small (unchanged) font size.

Comment: You might be able to use HTML as the text, and set `style="font-size:10px;"`

Comment: That's a great idea! I will try it out. Nevertheless, I will keep the question open, because other tweaks (not related to font size) might need a handle to the `QInputDialog` object.

Comment: Hi @denvaar .Your approach works, but only for the displayed informative text. The input text field has still the default font.

Comment: can you not just do something like `input_dialog = QInputDialog` then `input_dialog.setFont(font)` ?

Comment: I don't know what parameters I should give to the constructor of `QInputDialog`. You know, there are several types of input dialogs..

Comment: @K.Mulier. The documentation for [QInputDialog](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputdialog.html) seems quite clear, and is not greatly different from [QMessageBox](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html).

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled by the fact that to show the `QInputDialog()`, one needs to invoke the `getText(..)` function (or `getInt(..)`, depending on what you need). The simple `QMessageBox()` can be constructed first, and shown with `exec_()` later on.

Comment: @K.Mulier I'm not sure if it's possible without having to make your own custom dialog. You can try `dlg = QInputDialog(self)` then `dlg.setFont(font)` or even `dlg.setStyleSheet(""" * { font-size: 14pt; } """)` and then `dlg.getText('input dialog', 'Text here')` It didn't work for me, but didn't throw any errors. Not sure what to say.

Comment: @K.Mulier. No - those are static functions. You just need to call `exec_()`, same as any other dialog.

Comment: @ekhumoro and denvaar, I have applied your suggestions, and added an answer with the results. Of course, all the credit goes to you guys. If you like to add an answer with the content of your comments, then I will upvote it and check it as the correct answer. It is only fair to say "thank you" for your help ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the comments of @denvaar and @ekhumoro, I got the solution. Here it is:

```
    # Create a custom font
    # ---------------------
    font = QFont()
    font.setFamily("Arial")
    font.setPointSize(10)

    # Create and show the input dialog
    # ---------------------------------
    inputDialog = QInputDialog(None)
    inputDialog.setInputMode(QInputDialog.TextInput)
    inputDialog.setWindowTitle('Input')
    inputDialog.setLabelText('Enter the name for this new file:')
    inputDialog.setFont(font)
    ok = inputDialog.exec_()
    filename = inputDialog.textValue()
    if(ok):
        print('Name of file = ' + filename)
    else:
        print('Cancelled')
```

Answer (score 0):

QInputDialog consists of QLabel, QLineEdit, and QPushButton. You can independently control their style using `setStyleSheet` method.

```py
def RequireInputText(Parent, Title="TextInput", Text="Text"):
    InputDialog = QInputDialog(None)
    InputDialog.setInputMode(QInputDialog.TextInput)
    InputDialog.setWindowTitle(Title)
    InputDialog.setLabelText(Text)

    InputDialog.setStyleSheet(
        """
        QLabel{
            font-size:20px;
            font-weight:bold;
            font-family:Arial;
        }
        QLineEdit{
            font-size:20px;
            font-weight:bold;
            font-family:Arial;
        }
        QPushButton{
            font-size:20px;
            font-weight:bold;
            font-family:Arial;
            border-style:solid;
            border-color:black;
            border-width:2px; 
        }
        """
    )

    Ok = InputDialog.exec_()
    if(Ok):
        InputText = InputDialog.textValue()
        return InputText
    else:
        return None
```